# Beamer frametitle continuation contingent on framebreak

Tags: beamer, frame-title

I have the following MWE. The result will title the first frame as "Frame 1", the second as "Frame 1 (II)" and the third as "Frame 2".

What I need is that the `frametitle continuation` also occurs on the first frame of frames that are created via `framebreak`, but not on frames that have no framebreak. I.e., this example should have the titles "Frame 1 (I)", "Frame 2 (II)", and "Frame 2". 
However, when removing the `from second` option, the third frame will also have a roman (I) added to its title.

How can I tell LaTeX to **only** add "(I)" to a frame title if the frame is the first of several frames due to the use of `framebreak`?

I could not find a solution to this online, which made me wonder if I am trying something that I should not try in the first place - I want to have to change the frame title and layout only once, even though the (closely related) content will spread over 2 or 3 frames, and the `framebreak` option seems suitable, no?

```
\documentclass[t, sansserif, onlymath, 10pt]{beamer}

\setbeamertemplate{frametitle continuation}[from second][(\insertcontinuationcountroman )]


\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]\frametitle{Frame 1}
testtest1a

\framebreak

testtest1b
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]\frametitle{Frame 2}
testtest2
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Is `allowframebreaks` needed for *Frame 2* ?

Comment: No, it is not needed. You are right, when removing it, no frame continuation occurs. Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

The *frame title continuation  text* is only added if the frame is defined with the `allowframebreaks` option which allows the frame content to be broken up into several frames.

To surround  the *frame title continuation numbers* by two parentheses we can use: `\addtobeamertemplate{frametitle continuation}{(}{)}`

And also removing the `allowframebreaks` frame option will automatically remove the frame title continuation text.

```
\documentclass[ sansserif, onlymath, 10pt]{beamer}

\addtobeamertemplate{frametitle continuation}{(}{)}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]
\frametitle{Frame broken up into two frames}
\centering
First page content of the frame

\framebreak

Second page content of the frame

\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Single frame}

\centering
Frame content 

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]